# Listar datos omitiendo repetidos y sumarlos en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

pagos y los campos que tiene son `idpagos`, `codigo_empleado`, `fecha_pago`, `trimestre`, `monto_pago`

el trimestre de pago es porque a los empleados se le pagan 15 y ultimo de cada mes y yo los estoy identificando como 1 para el primer trimestre y 2 para el segundo trimestre.

Lo que quiero es que se me muestre todo el listado de los pagos de cada empleado de manera que no se me repitan y sumar los montos pagados de ambos trimestres por cada empleado.

He intentado con esto:

```
SELECT codigo_empleado, SUM(monto_pago)
FROM pagos WHERE MONTH(fecha_pago)=9 AND YEAR(fecha_pago)=2017
```

Pero me muestra solo una codigo_empleado y la suma del total de todos los montos pagados de todos los empleados en ese mes.

Comment: No estoy comprendiendo bien la pregunta. Puedes agregar datos de ejemplo de la tabla `pagos` y un ejemplo del resultado que quieres?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que lo que deseas es agrupar los montos totales de pago de empleado por cada mes (trimestre, como lo llamas. 15 y último). Podrías hacerlo de esta forma para que te lo agrupe por mes y año:

```
SELECT codigo_empleado, SUM(monto_pago) AS MontoTotal, MONTH(fecha_pago) AS MES, YEAR(fecha_pago) AS 'AÑO' 

FROM pagos

GROUP BY codigo_empleado, YEAR(fecha_pago), MONTH(fecha_pago)
```

Sería algo parecido a esto:

[image: Sería algo parecido a esto]

Sin embargo sería ideal contar con mayor información acerca de la estructura de las tablas y la información que estás alojando en ellas para entender tu pregunta.